# Adding more than one class html

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add more than one class in html?
Here is what i've tried:

```
<a href="#" class="class1" class="class2">My Text</a>
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you can only declare the `class` attribute once per HTML element. Just separate the classes you want to apply by a space.

```
<a href="#" class="class1 class2">My Text</a>
```

If you declare the class attribute more than once, all definitions beyond the first will be ignored, so in your code `.class2` will not be applied to your link.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course you can! But you do it all inside a single class attribute:

```
<a href="#" class="class1 class2">My Text</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="#" class="class1 class2">My Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the global class attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).

> The class global attribute is a space-separated list of the classes of
>   the element.

Use a single class attribute and separate additional classes with a space.

`<a href="#" class="class1 class2 class3">My Text</a>`